# Cursor exercise not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

Any idea why this code doesn't work in Sql Server please?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sum_salaries(OUT sum INTEGER) 
  LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
    DECLARE p_sum INTEGER;
    DECLARE p_sal INTEGER;
    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT SALARY FROM EMPLOYEE;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';

     SET p_sum = 0;

     OPEN c;

     FETCH FROM c INTO p_sal;

     WHILE(SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
        SET p_sum = p_sum + p_sal;
        FETCH FROM c INTO p_sal; 
     END WHILE;

     CLOSE c;

     SET sum = p_sum;

  END%
```

It gives all sorts of errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sum_salaries, Line 3 Incorrect
>   syntax near 'OUT'. Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure sum_salaries,
>   Line 6 'INTEGER' is not a recognized CURSOR option. Msg 155, Level 15,
>   State 2, Procedure sum_salaries, Line 7 'INTEGER' is not a recognized
>   CURSOR option. Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure sum_salaries,
>   Line 9 'CHAR' is not a recognized CURSOR option. Msg 102, Level 15,
>   State 1, Procedure sum_salaries, Line 15 Incorrect syntax near
>   'p_sal'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sum_salaries, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DO'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   sum_salaries, Line 19 Incorrect syntax near 'p_sal'. Msg 102, Level
>   15, State 1, Procedure sum_salaries, Line 24 Incorrect syntax near
>   '='.

Alternatively if you can point me to an ample article/site that teaches the use of cursors, that would be great too. This example was taken from: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0024361.html&resultof=%22%63%75%72%73%6f%72%22%20

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It's not T-SQL. This code isn't designed for SQL Server.

Comment: SqlServer version of those (DB2) docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181441.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need cursor to do that

```
create procedure sum_salaries
(
    @sum int output
) 
as
begin
    select @sum = sum(salary) from employee
end
```

But if you want to use cursor, try that

```
create procedure sum_salaries
(
    @sum int output
) 
as
begin
    declare @p_sum int, @p_sal int

    declare c cursor for
        select salary from employee

    set @p_sum = 0

    open c

    fetch from c into @p_sal

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        set @p_sum = @p_sum + @p_sal
        fetch from c into @p_sal
    end

    close c
    deallocate c

    set @sum = @p_sum
end
```